# How do I scrape a url from html when href is a file directory

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to web scraping. I'm trying to extract a list of URLs from a webpage but the href contains a directory instead of a url. Is there a way to get the URLs instead?

My code:

```
url='https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/bestsellers'
elements = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(elements, "html.parser")
for link in soup.findAll('a',attrs={'class':"leftAlignedImage"}):
    print (link['href'])
```

Output:

```
/book/show/5060378-the-girl-who-played-with-fire
/book/show/968.The_Da_Vinci_Code
/book/show/4667024-the-help
/book/show/2429135.The_Girl_with_the_Dragon_Tattoo
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment to the OP (@adib) than an answer. Your approach looks good to me, but you can avoid the need to do a `replace` by splitting the URL into 2 parts, at the start:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

baseUrl = 'https://www.goodreads.com'
path = '/shelf/show/bestsellers'
page = requests.get(baseUrl + path)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
for link in soup.findAll('a',attrs={'class':"leftAlignedImage"}):
    print (baseUrl + link['href'])
```

This will give you results like these:

```
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5060378-the-girl-who-played-with-fire
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/968.The_Da_Vinci_Code
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4667024-the-help
```

Comment: This is more common way to concatenate when the entire URL is not being captured

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with replace, I'm not sure if there's a better solution.

```
print(link['href'].replace('/book/show/','https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/'))
```